# How to get widths along specific directions in model ellipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image, ellipse

I generated a model of an ellipse using x- and y-coordinates as inputs into `skimage.measure.EllipseModel`. This worked well, and I now have parameters of the model ellipse: `[x_center, y_center, a, b, theta]`. Simply computing `2*a` and `2*b` will give me the full widths of the major and minor axes, respectively. But how can I find these widths at other locations?

Specifically, I want to compute the widths along the horizontal, vertical, and both diagonals (which correspond to 45° and 135° from the x-axis, respectively). Since my ellipse is rotated (by 93° from the x-axis), the major and minor axis widths do not give me the ones I want. What is a simple way to measure these widths?

Comment: That sounds more like a geometry question. This should give you the answer you need: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432907/481745